# Saving does not work when exception is handled

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm facing a situation I can't even find a way to debug.

I have the following `spring-data` repositories:

**IntegrationLogRepository**

```
public interface IntegrationLogRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<IntegrationLog, Long> {

}
```

**FooRepository**

```
public interface FooRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, Long> {

}
```

And on my business logic I have something like the following:

```
IntegrationLog log = new IntegrationLog();
log.setTimestamp(new Date());

try {
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    // Build the Foo object...

    fooRepository.save(foo);
    log.setStatus("OK");
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.setStatus("NOK");
} finally {
    integrationLogRepository.save(log);
}
```

When the integrations runs fine, the `log` is saved with the `OK` status. Everything is fine. But when I have an exception, for some reason `integrationLogRepository.save(log)` doesn't do nothing. I mean nothing NOTHING: No exception is thrown and I can't see any hibernate query being executed on my WebLogic console. The log is not persisted...

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Following are my dependencies:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services"
runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket"
compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.3.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final'
```

Running on Spring Boot `1.5.15.RELEASE`, Java `1.7` and WebLogic `12.1.3`.

Thanks!

Comment: is assume there is @Transactional on the entire method?

Comment: You mean on the method with my business logic? There is no @Transactional... Should it have? Can you explain why?

Comment: I just tried annotating it with @Transactional and had the same result: nothing happens :/

Comment: Well, you could add @Transactional(noRollbackFor = {Exception.class}) to cross out the rollback as the culprit

Comment: Is there any kind of exception log on the console? Does the code runs through your catch and finally blocks?

Comment: @VitorSantos, no exceptions on console... I explicity surrounded the `.save()` on the `finally` block with a `try/catch`. No exception is thrown and the `.save()` is executed.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski even with the `noRollBackFor` it didnt work. One thing though: Debugging inside the spring code I could see an exception being thrown: `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!;`. Apparently spring itself catches it or something... I'm checking what it might be...

Comment: You could try with `integrationLogRepository.saveAndFlush(log)` so the changes are persisted before the rollback

Comment: Even with a flush, it will be inside the same transactional context. It will be rolledback anyway.

Comment: Ok! I ""solved"" it. Annotating the method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` seems to make it work. Now if someone could explain to me why and if this is the right thing, I would gladly give the award points n_n'

Comment: I tried searching for the exception @JoãoMenighin posted. It's usually related to long transactions, and the container interrupting and rolling back.

Comment: @VitorSantos, yes I also saw it... Maybe the exception was even because I was debugging and keeping the transaction opened for so long... Maybe is not even related...

Comment: From spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED): "Do not support a current transaction; rather always execute non-transactionally." . My poor diagnosis is that there is something messing with your transaction. It's working now because this method is working in a non transactional context.

Comment: Considering the initial problem, I have faced a similar situation before when I had a method that saved/changed data on the DB, but for some reason the transaction was configured as `readOnly=true`. There was no exceptions thrown, but everything was always rolled back. It started behaving correctly when I configured as `readOnly=false`. But I don't see how it could happen in your case. Is this going on in the entire app? Or just this piece of code?

Comment: It seems to happens always when I have this flow of `catching exception -> persisting on finally`. Didn't have any other problem like this.... Still searching for the reason.

Comment: Beside applying `@Transactional` annotation on class or method level, a simple workaround, if MySQL used, change table engine type to `MyISAM` instead of `InnoDB`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception that was thrown is also rolling back the integration log save.
If you want to have the log saved, you have to give it a separate transaction when saving.

Abstract the log repository to a service and on the service method that saves the log add the transaction that creates a new transaction.

```
@Service
public class IntegrationLogService {

    private final IntegrationLogRepository logRepository;

    @Autowired
    public IntegrationLogService(IntegrationLogRepository logRepository) {
        this.logRepository = logRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save(Log log) {
        this.logRepository.save(log);
    }
}
```

In your business replace

```
finally {
    integrationLogRepository.save(log);
}
```

with

```
finally {
    integrationLogService.save(log);
}
```

**Edit**

Why setting `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` on the business layer worked?

To understand why it worked, we need to first look at what happens when one calls `save` on a repository in spring that uses `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`.

Spring tries to determine the `TransactionAttribute`'s on the method and targetClass. For the method `save` and class `CrudRepository`, in short it did not find any. Spring uses `SimpleJpaRepository` as the default implementation of the `CrudRepository`, if it did not find any transactional attributes on yours it will use the one specified in `SimpleJpaRepository`.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity)
```

The default propagation on `@Transactional` is required.

```
Propagation propagation() default Propagation.REQUIRED;
```

> Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.

As you can see from the documentation above, if no transaction is specified it will create a new one. So when you set the transaction on the business layer to `NOT_SUPPORTED` (Execute non-transactionally), the actual `CrudRepository` did create it's own transaction which means the rollback would not affect it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It makes sense to me, I will try. Can you explain why the `Propagation.NOT_SUPORTED` works?

Comment: It did work! Thanks! I really need to understand more how Transactions work with spring/jpa. If you have any article please recommend. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Propagation.NOT_SUPORTED` worked because it basically "says": this method will not run in a transaction. So, when an exception was thrown, spring did not rollback any successful operation. Rentius answer makes perfect sense (it worked after all!). I feel a bit stupid for not realizing the problem before.

Comment: @VitorSantos the default for spring is to run any method in a single transaction? I'm asking because I didn't have the `@Transactional` anotation and this problem was happening.

Comment: You are using spring boot. I would need to see your code do be sure, bute there is a high chance that transactions are being set in a auto config or something similar.

Comment: Happy to help João. You can go and have a look at https://vladmihalcea.com/, he is a hibernate developer advocate at Red Hat. The other well know site for spring related content is https://www.baeldung.com.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address why NOT_SUPPORTED worked.