# Running transaction on different bean throws exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions, transactional

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868447/saving-does-not-work-when-exception-is-handled/53870006#53870006) question and implemented the answer. It worked fine but now that I'm handling more data and it is not working as expected. Explaining:
I'm building integration with JMS. By the end of the integration process I must log the integration no matter what. To do so, I have build a `@Service` that saves a log in a new transaction. If I use the service, I'm getting an exception. If I execute the same logic of the service in the same bean it works fine. Let me show some code:

**The listener**

```
public class JMSListenerIntegration {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationHandler integrationHandler;

    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationLogRepository logRepository; // extends JpaRepository

    @JmsListener(...)
    public void onReceive(Message message) {

        List<Dto> dtos = // Unmarshall the message

        // A log for this integration already exists
        // On receiving a message, it changes status from RUNNING to OK or NOK
        IntegrationLog log = logRepository.findAlreadyExistingLog();

        try {

            // The integration handler persist 100+ records, each one in a new transaction
            boolean success = integrationHandler.handle(dtos);
            if (success) 
                log.setStatus("OK");
            else 
                log.setStatus("NOK");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.setStatus("NOK");
        } finally {
            logService.save(log);
            // this.saveLog(log);  // THIS WORKS
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void saveLog(IntegrationLog log) {
        logRepository.saveAndFlush(log);
    }

}
```

**LogService**

```
@Service
public class LogService {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationLogRepository logRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save(IntegrationLog log) {
        logRepository.saveAndFlush(log);
    }

}
```

If I run the code using the `saveLog()` function defined on my `JMSListenerIntegration` it works fine. If, instead, I try to use my `LogService` class it does not work. I see on the log a hibernate query for selecting a log and then, after some good 20s, I get an error:

```
2019-01-02 20:21:35.649  WARN 21112 --- [ (self-tuning)'] onizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl : HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
2019-01-02 20:21:35.652  WARN 21112 --- [enerContainer-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2019-01-02 20:21:35.652 ERROR 21112 --- [enerContainer-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 31 seconds
BEA1-36996D3224E23057A4BD]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
2019-01-02 20:21:35.657  INFO 21112 --- [enerContainer-1] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.example.models.IntegrationLog#6]
2019-01-02 20:21:35.692  WARN 21112 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not load an entity: [com.example.models.IntegrationLog#6]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.example.models.IntegrationLog#6]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:525) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy400.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.services.IntegrationLogService.save(IntegrationLogService.kt:20) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at com.example.services.IntegrationLogService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$98a7fdd9.invoke(<generated>) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.example.services.IntegrationLogService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9eee6d68.save(<generated>) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at com.example.integrations.listeners.MalhaJmsListener.onReceive(MalhaJmsListener.kt:88) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at com.example.integrations.listeners.MalhaJmsListener$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1357be2d.invoke(<generated>) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.example.integrations.listeners.MalhaJmsListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9de82e4.onReceive(<generated>) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at com.example.integrations.listeners.ListenersManager$startupListeners$1.onMessage(ListenersManager.kt:42) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:744) ~[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:682) ~[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649) ~[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:235) [spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168) [spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160) [spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057) [spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.example.models.IntegrationLog#6]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2213) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4083) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1142) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2762) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2741) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:983) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:843) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:825) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:830) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor252.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy386.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor252.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:300) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy386.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:515) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:500) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 30 seconds
BEA1-01E60652F53A3057A4BD]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkIfRolledBack(JTSConnection.java:202) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.checkConnection(JTSConnection.java:220) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:95) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_weblogic_jdbc_sqlserverbase_ddeb.next(Unknown Source) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:974) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:936) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2209) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar:5.1.16.Final]
        ... 81 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks,

---

**EDIT**

Following the comments suggestion I have changed my `LogService` to look like:

```
@Service
public class LogService {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationLogRepository logRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save(IntegrationLog plainLog) {

        IntegrationLog log = logRepository.findOne(plainLog.getId());

        log.setStatus(plainLog.getStatus());
        log.setFoo(plainLog.getFoo());
        // ...

        logRepository.saveAndFlush(log);
    }

}
```

And I still get the same error. And I start to think it is related to the previous operations done on `integrationHandler.handle(dtos)`. In this method, I persist a lot of records. The logic looks like:

```
public boolean handle(List<Dto> dtos) {
   boolean result = true;
   for (Dto dto in dtos) {
       try {

           Foo foo = new Foo();
           foo.setProp1(dto.getProp1());
           foo.setProp2(dto.getProp2());
           saveFoo(foo);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           logger.error(e.getMessage());
           result = false;
       }
   }
   return result;
}


// Now I know this is not running in its own transaction, right?
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public saveFoo(Foo foo) {
    fooRepository.save(foo);
}
```

If I don't call the `handle()` method (so the persist operations are not performed) the `LogService` works just fine. I can only imagine the transaction for saving the `Foo`'s are taking too long and the transaction for `findOne` is gettint timed out (can't find a reason why) giving the `could not load an entity` (I even tried calling `findOne(6)` which is a valid ID in my database). Maybe this is not the right way to persist the data...? Really lost here guys. Any help is appreciated :/

Comment: You're trying to load an IntegrationLog entity which doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Hi JB. Why would a `saveAndFlush()` do that?

Comment: Yuck. Separate the listener, the service layer (where the transaction should start) and the dao into three separate classes.

Comment: Because saveAndFlush calls merge() if the entity is supposed to already exist (i.e. has an ID), and merge() first loads the entity, then updates it. So if you create it in the outer transaction, loading it again from the inner transaction won't find it, since the outer transaction hasn't been committed yet. Using the same instance of an entity in two separate transaction is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: I doubt it, but anyway, you're trying to bind the same entity instance to two different persistence context. Don't do that.

Comment: @JBNizet I didnt create it. I got it from the database on the first place, so it should exist on the database, shouldn't it? Anyway, any ideas on how to solve it then?

Comment: Pass the ID of the log and its status to the service, and let it get the log, update its status and save it.

Comment: It doesn't really seem like you're doing logging. Consider renaming it for posterity.

Comment: Floegipoky and wild_nothing, this is just pseudo code guys, chill @JBNizet, please explain a little more (in an answer so I can give you the check mark): Does using another bean uses another Persistance context? I'm asking because if I use the saveLog() method on my JMSListenerIntegration it works. I really would like to only pass the log to be persisted in another transaction to the service (because in really I'm not just changing the status but a bunch of other properties). Is there a way to do that? Like pass also the PersistanceContext maybe...?

Comment: No. starting another transaction is what starts another persistence context, since the persistence context is bound by Spring to the transaction.

Comment: @JBNizet  But then it doesn't exaplin why running `saveLog` works since it is also annotated with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it does, because Spring can only start a new transaction when you cross a bean boundary(i.e. when you call another bean): when you do that, you call the transactional proxy that wraps the other bean, and the proxy starts a transaction. When you call `this.saveLog()`, the proxy is never called, and thus no transaction is started.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried what you said but couldnt get it through... Could you please check my Edit?

Comment: @JBNizet I have noticed I got some errors before the `could not load entity` message. I edited the question with them. Im searching about it but if you know anything about it please let me know